# Cannot convert type 'WpfA.DataClass.tblGroup' to 'WpfA.Group'

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

The table has two columns.

columns1= IdGroup

columns2= Hgroup

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetData();
    }
    private void SetData()
    {
        using (DataClass.DataClassesAccDataContext DataContext = new DataClass.DataClassesAccDataContext())
        {
            List<Group> myGroup = (Group)DataContext.tblGroup.ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public bool Selecting { get; set; }
}
```

error :

Cannot convert type 'WpfA.DataClass.tblGroup' to 'WpfA.Group'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `tblGroup`, which is what gets returned from your LINQ query, is not an instance of `Group`, because `tblGroup` does not derive from `Group`.  You have a couple of options:

1. Change Group to being an interface, and have tblGroup implement this
   interface (assuming tblGroup has all the properties specified in
   Group).
2. Use a LINQ Select to project out Group objects instead of
   tblGroup objects.  However note that these Group objects would be
   disconnected from the database -- e.g. if you needed to save changes
   to the Group objects you would have to copy them back into tblGroup
   objects.

(Note also that tblGroups.ToList()[0] will return a single item, not a list.  So you should probably be trying to assign it to a Group rather than a `List<Group>`.  Also, if you only want the first result, it's more efficient to use the LINQ `First()` operator rather than `ToList()[0]`; this will avoid fetching unwanted records from the database.)